# Generating url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

I have a problem with url in Laravel

```
<td> Website: <a href="{{url($data[0]->internet)}}" target="_blank">{{$data[0]->internet}}</a></td>
```

where `internet` is some website name, for example `www.foo.com`

The problem is that output URL is `http://localhost/www.foo.com` instead of `http://www.foo.com`

Comment: target="_blank" ?

Comment: As I can see from laravel documentation: `The url helper may be used to generate arbitrary URLs for your application. The generated URL will automatically use the scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) and host from the current request:` , so why you are using url() ?

Comment: What does "_in new tab of particular company_" mean? What does "_tried but not working_" mean? Setting `target="_blank"` is the preferred way to go. If that is "_not working_" for you you might have a setting/plugin that prevents new tabs to be opened or you are changing the wrong code. `Inspect element` in your browser's developer tools and make sure `target="_blank"` is there.

Comment: Ooohhook, so your problem is the URL for the company is not correct? Opening in a new tab works as expected? If so you might want to rephrase your question. And use `$data[0]->internet` instead of `url($data[0]->internet)`. Kudos to @D.Dimitrov

Comment: Sorry for question was not presented properly.. target="blank" is working properly but opening incorrect URL.. Without url helper it gives me output as 
  http://localhost/foo/bar/www.foo.com

Answer (score 0):

change the target attribute `target="blank"` to `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<a href="{!! $data[0]->internet !!}" target="_blank">{{$data[0]->internet}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to

```
<a href="{{ $data[0]->internet }}" target="_blank">{{$data[0]->internet}}</a>
```

---

As stated in the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls

> The url helper may be used to generate arbitrary URLs for your
>   application. The generated URL will automatically use the scheme (HTTP
>   or HTTPS) and host from the current request

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

echo url("/posts/{$post->id}");

// http://example.com/posts/1
```

In your case you won't need the url helper function.

---

Also make use of the http or https protocol in this format:
http://www.foo.com or https://www.foo.com to make an absolute url instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

> If your variable internet is some website name, for example
>   www.foo.com and you need to link this URl in anchor tag you dont need
>   to call this variable inside url() function you can simply use that
>   variable to link the url in anchor tag.
>
> If you want to get the base URL of your site then you can use url()
>   fucntion which return base url of your website.

Just replace below line with your code

```
<td> 
Website: 
<a href="{{$data[0]->internet}}" target="_blank">{{$data[0]->internet}}</a>
</td>
```